# Как устранить ошибки (at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(Unknown Source))?

Tags: java, eclipse

Делаю небольшие уроки отсюда: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/ (переписываю короче), вот, значит, и в уроке с выводом [графического файла](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/basics/) (в конце)
и в уроке с [анимацией](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/animation/) столкнулся со следующими сообщениями из консоли:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at bardejov.Board.<init>(Board.java:16)
  at bardejov.Image.<init>(Image.java:10)
  at bardejov.Image.main(Image.java:20)
```

Работаю в еклипсе, и видимо, я что-то не догоняю. Думаю, он не находит запрашиваемые графические файлы, клал в папку src, пробовал в эклипсе добавлять файл в проект, но что-то безуспешно (хотя файл, типа добавился).

(Не знаю, нужна ли эта информация, но все таки: `JavaSE-1.6, Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.0 Build id: I20110613-1736`.)

Что я делаю не так? (Я новичок и все такое в этом деле.)

**UPD**
а может это быть, из за того, что я в одном проекте создаю несколько пакетов и в двух из них имена классов совпадают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гугл рулит! Разобрался.

Помогло вот это:

> File -> New -> Java Project -> Project name: example1 -> Finish.

Щелкаем правой клавишей по проекту

> example1 -> New -> Class -> Name: TestZoomImage -> Finish.

Вставляем код. Копируем изображение pic.jpg(к примеру), щелкаем правой клавишей на

> example1 –> paste. Run As -> Java Application.

(Важно! Не вручную копировать картинку в папку пакета, а именно вставить картинку в эклипсе.)

[Источник](http://www.javatalks.ru/sutra69053.php).